# pymongo - how to get single policy for each customer by last date and sort all policy by date?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, date

I have two collection

person collection

```
[{'_id':1, 'name': 'aaaa'},
{'_id':2, 'name': 'bbbb'},
{'_id':3, 'name': 'cccc'}]
```

policy collection

```
[{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':2, 'expiry_date':01-12-2017},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':1, 'expiry_date':01-12-2019},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':2, 'expiry_date':05-12-2020},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':1, 'expiry_date':04-12-2018},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':3, 'expiry_date':06-12-2017}]
```

result should be
first it get policy with maximum expiry date and then sort it by date.

```
[{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':1, 'expiry_date':01-12-2019},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':2, 'expiry_date':05-12-2020},
{'_id':yyyy, 'person_id':3, 'expiry_date':06-12-2017}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw, use always proper `Date` objects.
After conversion to `Date`, you can apply sorting:

```
db.policy.aggregate([
   { $set: { expiry_date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$expiry_date", format: "%d-%m-%Y"} } } },
   { $sort: { expiry_date: -1} },
   { $group: { _id: "$person_id", expiry_date: { $first: "$expiry_date" } } }
])
```

Or you can use

```
   { $group: { _id: "$person_id", expiry_date: { $max: "$expiry_date" } } }
```

which does not require any `$sort`

Comment: thanks for your answer actualy in real my date are not string. please write code for python and should i group person_id ?

Comment: Yes correct. In this case you can skip the `$set` stage. Sorry, I never used Python, so I cannot help there.